# collapsible toolbar not collapsing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

[image]

As you can see above, when I scroll from 'Foliage Plants', the CollapsibleToolbar collapses as expected but when I drag from any product image, the page scrolls beneath AppBarLayout. Why is this happening and how to fix this? Ive tried setting VerticalRecyclerView.setNestedScrolling to false but that didn't work.

My home page layout is structured as follows
[image]

Structure of fragment located inside ViewPager

[image]

Layout of homepage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_productdetail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_home_categoryfooter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/search_background_list"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_home_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_home_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/search_background_list"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="No Results Found"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <experttag.nurserylive.util.ui.widget.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_search"
            android:name="experttag.nurserylive.fragment.SearchFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Layout of the fragment inside ViewPager is as follows

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/recyclerview_productoverview"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/windowBackground"/>
```

Layout of item inside @id/recyclerview_productoverview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_section_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <experttag.nurserylive.util.ui.widget.WhitneySemiBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="TOP FEATURED"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_item_viewall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:tint="#000"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_item_section"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_section_header"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try removing `enteralways` flag in layout_scrollflags attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) on inner Horizontal RecyclerView solved this problem for me.

Comment: It is not working in the case of ViewPager2 inside recyclerview item.